# Overriding methods from a derived class

Tags: overriding

I have the following coding:-

Progam 1

```
class Person :

    '''A base to define Person properties.'''

    def __inti__( self , name ):
        self.name = name

    def speak( self , msg = '(Calling The Base Class)' ):
        print( self.name , msg )
```

Program 2

```
from Person import *
'''A derived class to define Man properties.'''

class Man( Person ):
        def speak( self , msg ):
                print( self.name , ':\n\tHello!' , msg )
```

Program 3

```
from Person import *
'''A derived class to define Hombre properties.'''

class Hombre( Person ):
        def speak( self , msg ):
                print( self.name , ':\n\tHola!' , msg )
```

Program 4

```
from Man import *
from Hombre import *

guy__1 = Man('Richard')
guy__2 = Hombre('Ricardo')
guy__1.speak( 'It\'s a beautiful evening.\n' )
guy__2.speak( 'Es una tarde hermosa.\n' )
Person.speak( guy__1 )
Person.speak( guy__2 )
```

I get the following error;-
guy__1 = Man('Richard')
TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Answer (score 0):

change

```
def __inti__( self , name ):
```

to

```
def __init__( self , name ):
```

Comment: Thank you.  I must be tired!